# Android onCreate onResume

Tags: android, oncreate, onresume

I have a problem.
When I start for the first time my android application, in the main activity both the `onCreate` and the `onResume` are called. but I want to be called only the onCreate.

What can I do?

Comment: remove the onResume() if u don't want.it won't affect.

Comment: Check this answer it may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167

Answer (score 42):

According to the SDK docs what you are seeing is the intended behavior. Have a look at the flowchart in the docs for Activity - [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Programmatically you can overcome this by keeping an instance member to track whether onResume has been called before - the first time it is called, set the variable and return e.g.

```
private boolean resumeHasRun = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!resumeHasRun) {
        resumeHasRun = true;
        return;
    }
    // Normal case behavior follows
}
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I receive a "Suspended (exception RuntimeException)" when I try to set resumeHasRun = true.  Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of this you should use Activity's onRestart() method, it is intented exactly for that use case.

Comment: Provided that your activity gets stopped (`onStopped()`), then @FenixVoltres is correct, in that, you should use `onRestart()`.

Answer (score 15):

The correct answer is to use `Activity`'s `onRestart()` method. This is probably what you have been looking for.

Comment: Not necessarily. `onRestart()` is called only if the activity has stopped.

Comment: You're right, but the answer to above question was to move code from `onResume()` (which is called also when activity is created) to `onRestart()`, which is not, what was the point.

Comment: @bowmanb Correct, but without knowing his intent, in most cases, `onRestart()` is what you'd want here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything, as this is how the Activity lifecycle works.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle for a diagram that shows the lifecycle.

Comment: ok thanks..  so if the onResume is called any time there is no way to make the activity to behave in a certain way at a first access, and in another way when is called back.. am I right?

Comment: @Alessio Yes, look at the `onRestart()` method. See @Fenix's answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the API the Activity Lifecycle always calls onResume before showing the activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

I guess you could make a global boolean for a first access and set it to false.
Then override the onResume and check the variable.
If false, set it to true and return,
if true, call super.onResume.

Should work, but I don't know if it can be handled simpler and I don't have access to the sdk here to test it.