# Android - Prevent onResume() function if Activity is loaded for the first time (without using SharedPreferences)

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle, onresume

In my current application the onResume function is triggered when I load an Activity for the first time . I looked into the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), but I didn't find a way to prevent this from happening.

Can I prevent the onResume() function from loading when an Activity is loaded for the first time, without using SharedPreferences?

Comment: Why don't you want to do it? What is so important to break a consistent lifecycle of Android? Cannot you do it in the onCreate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android onCreate onResume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175679/android-oncreate-onresume)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android onCreate onResume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175679/android-oncreate-onresume)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Firstly, as RvdK says, you should not modify the Android Activity lifecycle, you probably have to re-design your activity behavior in order to be compliant with it.

Anyway, this is the best way that I see:

1.Create a boolean variable inside your Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
  boolean shouldExecuteOnResume;
  // The rest of the code from here..
}
```

2.Set it as false inside your onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(){
  shouldExecuteOnResume = false
}
```

3.Then in your onResume:

```
public void onResume(){
  if(shouldExecuteOnResume){
    // Your onResume Code Here
  } else{
     shouldExecuteOnResume = true;
  }

}
```

In this way your `onResume` will not be executed the first time (`shouldExecuteOnResume` is false) but it will be instead executed all the other times that the activity is loaded (because `shouldExecuteOnResume` will be true).
If the activity is then killed (by the user or the system) the next time it will be loaded the `onCreate` method will be called again so `onResume` will not be executed, etc..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also used the same method that you mentioned, but when I launch the "MyActivity" activity from another activity, the variable shouldExecuteOnResume is reset. It seems that every time I call the MyActivity activity, a new instance is created instead of it using the existing instance. I want the app to use the existing instance of MyActivity.

Comment: you can try to make the variable static but I guess the problem is that you never know if/when your app is killed by the system. You can try to put some other controls in the onStop to check what happens..

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I made shouldExecuteOnResume static.

Comment: To avoid using static make your activity single task using `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. This will make it created only once and reused every time you call this activity and keep the shouldExecuteOnResume non static

Comment: Hello, when I tried this, I got 'super not called exception'